# Aligning different multiple form inputs on one line

Tags: html, forms, input, alignment

I'm trying to align multiple form inputs as well as some text on one line in two scenarios (vertical-align:bottom, and not specific alignment) Please see the attached code where you can see how just about all elements aligns differently.

What is the best/proper way to solve this? Would really appreciate if someone could modify the code so all the elements aligns properly.

Thank you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
Sample 1, with vertical align bottom:<br>
<font style="font-size:45px;vertical-align:bottom"></font>
<input type="text" style="width:100px;height:45px;font-size:45px;vertical-align:bottom">
<input type="checkbox" style="width:45px;height:45px;vertical-align:bottom">
<input type="button" value="Search" style="height:45px;vertical-align:bottom">
<br><br>
Sample 2, without vertical align bottom:<br>
<font style="font-size:45px"></font>
<input type="text" style="width:100px;height:45px;font-size:45px">
<input type="checkbox" style="width:45px;height:45px">
<input type="button" value="Search" style="height:45px">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Side note, the `<font>` element hasn't been valid for decades

Answer (score 0):

It's because all inputs have different margins. Try setting the margin of all inputs to the same value.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
Sample 1, with vertical align bottom:<br>
<font style="font-size:45px;vertical-align:bottom; margin: 10px;"></font>
<input type="text" style="width:100px;height:45px;font-size:45px;vertical-align:bottom; margin: 10px;">
<input type="checkbox" style="width:45px;height:45px;vertical-align:bottom; margin: 10px;">
<input type="button" value="Search" style="height:45px;vertical-align:bottom; margin: 10px;">
```

Comment: This only solves the problem for checkbox in sample 1. The unicode magnifying glass is still unalligned, and on sample 2 it does nothing:
Before: https://jsfiddle.net/3fnwzqu6/
After: https://jsfiddle.net/srh45oLd/

Comment: You can simply add display: inline-block property to that font tag. And if you want to align all the items in the second example the easiest way is to use vertical-align since this alements are inline-blocks.

Comment: Doesn't seem to do much: https://jsfiddle.net/a4fqo8ey/

Comment: As I said, add display: inline-block property to the FONT tag, and user vertical-align:bottom in all elements. https://jsfiddle.net/29z7vhnc/